# How to convert a scaled dataframe back to original, essentially something like unscaling operation in Python

Tags: python, normalization, pca

There is a function in R to unscale but couldn't figure out Python equivalent for that.
I have a dataframe with shape(10000, 130), scaled it, performed PCA on it and got  a new frame with shape(10000,98). How do I get the original rows and column names for this new data frame.

The data frame after PCA has all numerical values for rows and column name data.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Take a look at `StandardScaler` or `MinMaxScaler` from `scikit-learn` library. They all have methods to fit to data, scale it and convert back to original state.

Comment: @pavel It offers a way to convert to a different range of numerical values but not the original dataframe

Comment: @mkgrieger1
pca = PCA(n_components=142)
pca.fit(X2)
X2_pca = pca.transform(X2)
print("original shape:   ", X2.shape)
print("transformed shape:", X2_pca.shape)
X2_pca = pd.DataFrame(X2_pca)